# How to build boost 1_59_0 for x64 using MSVC-14.0

Tags: python, c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

I would like to build boost 1.59.0 using the Visual Studio 2015 (Community). I followed the documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566807/how-to-build-boost-version-1-58-0-using-visual-studio-2015-enterprise). Specifically, I did:

1. Download boost 1.59.0 from http://www.boost.org/
2. Extract files (e.g. “C:\some_dir\boost_1_59_0”)
3. Open VS2015 x64 Native Tools Command prompt.
4. check compiler version with `where cl` with result `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.exe`
5. change into directory boost_1_59_0
6. call `bootstrap.bat` no errors are reported
7. call `b2 toolset=msvc-14.0 address-model=64 --with-python` as part of the output it will happily report `- 32 bit: yes`

When I try to build `libs\python\example\tutorial` it again reports `- 32 bit: yes` and results in the error `python34.lib(python34.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'`. I interpret this as: the python dll is x64 (as installed) but my target is 32 bit.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ahh yes I see the problem: MSVC.

Comment: Try to delete cached files: `b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd`, `b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86_amd64.cmd`, 
`b2_msvc_14.0_vcvarsall_x86_arm.cmd` from `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Local\Temp` and rebuild boost.

Comment: This might seem trivial, but did you also specify `address-model=64` when building `libs\python\example\tutorial`?

Comment: I tried once more deleting the cached files and also specifying `address-model=64` when building the tutorial. However, it stubbornly says ` - 32 bit: yes`. In addition I tried using mingw-64. With mingw-64 everything compiles fine in 64 bit. However, when the build process tries to run python, or I run the python example, python crashes. But that would be a different question.

Comment: Confusing as it is, `32 bit: yes` doesn't mean it's actually doing a 32-bit build; it only indicates what the default configuration would be if you didn't specify an `address-model`. Some info [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/boost-config-context-log-1-58-address-model-and-architecture-detection-td4674125.html#a4674135). Look at the library output paths in `bin.v2`: if you have some `address-model-64` directories in there, then it's most likely building for 64-bit.

Comment: Please check if BlueGo can build boost for you: https://bitbucket.org/Vertexwahn/bluego/src/default/

Answer (score 0):

At first run *VS2015 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt* item in <kbd>START</kbd> menu as **Administrator** and go to the boost library in `cmd`.

Now do the following steps :

1. bootstrap
2. b2 variant=debug,release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64 toolset=msvc-14.0