# Where can I find 64-bit version of vsvars32.bat?

Tags: visual-studio, nmake

I am compiling openssl for Amd64.The problem is i can't find 64-bit version of vsvars32.bat? Is there such a file or I have to edit vsvar32 for 64-bit version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify which version of Visual Studio you're using. There should be a file named `vcvarsall.bat` in the `VC` directory.

You can invoke that script with `x86_amd64` as the argument (i.e. `vcvarsall x86_amd64`), and it will take care of invoking the appropropriate script (on my VS 12.0 installation it will invoke `vcvars86_amd64.bat` in VC\bin\x86_amd64).

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2015.

Comment: See also here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/x4d2c09s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @Saleh: Did you install Common Tools for Visual C++ 2015? More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566807/how-to-build-boost-version-1-58-0-using-visual-studio-2015-enterprise

Comment: Oh , I found the vcvars64.bat file in the amd64 folder , That was what I was looking for , Thank you!