# LNK2001 error when using boost::numpy

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, boost

I am trying to call a C++ .dll from Python and return a numpy array. I am using

- Anaconda 2.7 x64
- Visual Studio 2013 update 5
- boost 1.63.0 prebuileded for lib64-msvc-12.0

I managed to compile this simple example frome [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/tutorial/index.html) and run it in Python:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}
```

I am unsure about the `#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB` but without it python could not open the pyd file. I suspected that python could not resolve the references to `MSVCR120.dll` in the dynamic build, but I am just guessing.

Next step was to include `<boost/python/numpy.hpp>` and follow [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/tutorial/ndarray.html) instuctions and start with just creating a `numpy::ndarray`. Yes, I am aware that void is in contradiction to the intention of getting values, I just wanted to keep things as simple as possible.

```
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
namespace p = boost::python;
namespace np = boost::python::numpy;

void getNPArray()
{
    Py_Initialize();
    np::initialize();
    p::object tu = p::make_tuple('a', 'b', 'c');
    np::ndarray const example_tuple = np::array(tu);
    return;
}
```

The import and namespace declarations compile without error.
At next step I encountered the linker error. While Py_Initialize() worked fine, the `np::initialize()` causes the linker to throw

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl
>   boost::python::numpy::initialize(bool)"
>   (?initialize@numpy@python@boost@@YAX_N@Z)

And `np::ndarray const example_tuple = np::array(tu)` causes a

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class
>   boost::python::numpy::ndarray __cdecl
>   boost::python::numpy::array(class boost::python::api::object const &)"
>   (?array@numpy@python@boost@@YA?AVndarray@123@AEBVobject@api@23@@Z)

As the linker is perfectly happy with the first example I am toally confused about what is going on here. I also tried to comment out all parts from the first example and just compile the second part witout any change in behaviour.

Any hints on how to make my linker happy are highly appreciated.

[update - issue solved] 
It turned out that the source of the errors is simply that the probuild version of boost comes without a `libboost_numpy-vc120-mt-1_63.lib` so i followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566807/how-to-build-boost-version-1-58-0-using-visual-studio-2015-enterprise#comment51092772_31566807) to build it. Using this parameters:

```
b2 -j8 --toolset=msvc-12.0  release link=static runtime-link=static address-model=64 --build-type=complete stage --with-python
```

The import which is now working for me looks like this:

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB  
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME "boost_numpy"
#include <boost/config/auto_link.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>
```

Comment: Boost build decides whether to build the boost-numpy library as part of the boost-python library based on whether executing python -c "import sys; sys.stderr = sys.stdout; import numpy; print(numpy.get_include())" succeeds or not. See https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/e22a75c8fd83f0e52adea4f48ef5f9fbbdf5b72c/src/tools/python.jam#L838-L857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required library is not pulled in automatically by `boost_numpy` like it is for other Boost components. To fix this, place these lines in one of your source files:

```
#define BOOST_LIB_NAME "boost_numpy"
#include <boost/config/auto_link.hpp>
```

This will use Boost's automatic linking feature to determine the appropriate `boost_numpy` library for your build configuration (such as `libboost_numpy-vc120-mt-1_63.lib`) and generate a `#pragma` that asks your linker to include it.

Those two lines probably should be included in `boost/python/numpy.hpp`. The omission may be a bug there.

Incidentally, those lines can be repeated as many times as necessary, changing the definition `LIB_BOOST_NAME` each time, to include any other missing Boost libraries. (`auto_link.hpp` intentionally does not use an include guard, thus permitting this type of usage.)

Comment: Works like charm. I can't express my gratitute for your answer!

Comment: unfortunatelly it turned out that it does not solve my issue. np::initialize() was commented out when i tested it the first time.

Comment: @user_na - Perhaps you need even more configuration options for your particular setup to include the correct library. You may need to `#define BOOST_DYN_LINK` also. Or you could include [this entire "config.hpp" file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/boostorg/python/bd7b8ecba5c211c3361c4a9af82a7a527bed384e/include/boost/python/numpy/config.hpp) rather than just adding those two lines. Otherwise, pay attention to the exact errors you're getting. I'd bet they've changed.

Comment: So I started a new project to trace the issue and in the clean project I got a message that libboost_numpy-vc120-mt-1_63.lib is missing using your additional define and include. And the lib was just not delivered with the prebuild version. Compiled it and it is now working. Your suggestion in the answer is still neccessary though to get it running. Thanks again for your help. I would upvote again if I could...