# Boost Python Numpy - Undefined reference to initialize

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, numpy, boost

I am having problems when linking the following code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE (MyLibrary)
{

    Py_Initialize() ;
    boost::python::numpy::initialize() ;

    ...

}
```

which returns:

```
undefined reference to `boost::python::numpy::initialize(bool)'
```

I am using Boost 1.68 with Python 3.6, compiled as follows:

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python=/usr/bin/python3 --with-python-version=3.6 --with-python-root=/usr/lib/python3.6
./b2 --with-python link=shared install
```

And I am linking using:

```
/usr/bin/c++ -shared
-o MyLibrary.so
MyLibrary.cpp.o
-L/usr/local/lib
-lpython3.6m
/usr/local/lib/libboost_python36.so
```

Any idea...?

Comment: Numpy routines are built into a separate library e.g. `libboost_numpy.so`. Check if that has actually been built, i believe it's built automatically if it (and the development headers etc) are installed in your python environment.

Comment: Do you know what headers are supposed to be present? No libboost_numpy.so has been built in my case, and I didn’t find any option or documentation in b2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to install the `python3-numpy` package first,
otherwise `libboost_numpy.so` does not get generated.

End of the story!

Comment: you're a legend lucas, very helpful

Comment: Thanks! This pointed me in the right direction. This seemed to resolve the problem in my case on Ubuntu 22.04: `sudo apt install --reinstall libboost-numpy-dev libboost-numpy1.74-dev libboost-numpy1.74.0 python3-numpy`